# scroll fixed position = jQuery Jank with offset top in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm trying to get 2 sets of classes to have fixed positions in jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $(".staticTextGrid").each(function(){

        $(this).css('margin-top',($(window).scrollTop() - $(this).parent().offset().top+160));

    });
    $(".staticTextGridTop").each(function(){

        $(this).css('margin-top',($(window).scrollTop() - $(this).parent().offset().top));

    });
});
```

This is what I'm doing but it doesn't want to play nice in safari (causing it to jank and jitter). Any points in the right direction would be great. My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what safari is doing that isn't playing nice so I can only have a stab at it. But sometimes safari doesn't render the page again on a css change. try adding this to the end of your function. It's not the best solution but it will at least confirm the problem! :)

```
$("body").addClass("tempClass").removeClass("tempClass");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response and sorry for not being clear. Its causing jankiness in safari. A jittery stutter that isn't present in other browsers. I tried what you suggested but its still jitters. Any other stabs at it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Ok check this fiddle out in safari or IE, https://jsfiddle.net/billNugz/y4x1cbcz/
It shows the jitter. Any help would be great. And props to http://ianlunn.co.uk for providing a base for me to hack around with.